# Unwanted SVG Behavior in Firefox - Repeating SVG gradient Background

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

### Summary

- **SVG image** (gradient) file encoded as `base64` then added as `CSS` background
- Super lite and works great. it also removes the need for vender prefixes
- Tested with `Chrome  / IE / Safari`  **no problems**
- **Issue with Firefox**: it will repeat the gradient instead of stretching to cover the area
- Setting background-size to cover fixes the issue, but then the
  gradient is not displayed properly (see images below)

---

### Images:

1. Here's what it looks like in **FF before adding**
   `{background-size:cover}`

   [image: ff repeats background if background-size:cover is not used]

---

2. Now, here is what it looks like **in FF after using**
   `{background-size:cover}`

   [image: ff displays incorrectly if background-size:cover is used]

---

3. Finally this is what it looks like in `Chrome / Safari / IE` **with
   or without** using `{background-size:cover}`

   **This is also my desired effect**

   [image: chrome displays the gradient properly whether background-size:cover is used or not]

### Question:

How can I make the background look the same in FF?

**Note:**  `{background-attachment: fixed}` works great, but it's too expensive - performance wise.

---

Here's what's **inside the SVG**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<radialGradient id="g97" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0%" cy="0%" r="200%">
<stop stop-color="#794444" offset="0"/>
<stop stop-color="#115594" offset="1"/>
</radialGradient>
<rect x="-50" y="-50" width="101" height="101" fill="url(#g97)" />
</svg>
```

### And Here's My Code;

```css
html {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8cmFkaWFsR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imc5NyIgZ3JhZGllbnRVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIGN4PSIwJSIgY3k9IjAlIiByPSIyMDAlIj4KPHN0b3Agc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzc5NDQ0NCIgb2Zmc2V0PSIwIi8+PHN0b3Agc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzExNTU5NCIgb2Zmc2V0PSIxIi8+CjwvcmFkaWFsR3JhZGllbnQ+CjxyZWN0IHg9Ii01MCIgeT0iLTUwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNnOTcpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
}
body {
  color: #aaa;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 92%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  padding-top: .8em;
}
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 94%;
  width: auto;
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
p {
  text-align: justify;
  word-spacing: -2px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 780px;
  padding: .8em;
}
p,
body,
.content {
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-1.jpg">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet landjaeger tongue burgdoggen t-bone ham filet mignon pastrami picanha shank strip steak ball tip tail capicola tenderloin ham hock. Brisket tenderloin strip steak, prosciutto bresaola jowl alcatra ham hock kielbasa ribeye pork
      belly pork loin porchetta andouille doner. Swine ribeye shank alcatra fatback bresaola drumstick. Short loin burgdoggen leberkas rump short ribs sirloin shankle meatloaf biltong porchetta ball tip frankfurter shoulder.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-2.jpg">
    <p>Frankfurter fatback sausage, turducken chicken short ribs shoulder corned beef ball tip alcatra. Spare ribs brisket sirloin kielbasa short loin, beef ribs jowl porchetta pig prosciutto doner tenderloin. Shankle burgdoggen biltong jowl chuck, landjaeger
      turkey picanha hamburger short loin. Fatback rump tail doner. Brisket cupim meatloaf picanha pastrami. Short ribs doner brisket ground round porchetta shank.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-4.jpg">
    <p>Chuck turkey jowl porchetta. Doner shank swine cupim pastrami pancetta turducken fatback pork tail boudin ham hock ball tip bresaola. Burgdoggen ground round pork flank beef ribs, tri-tip ham tongue spare ribs short loin pork belly boudin meatball
      andouille. Salami ball tip tri-tip doner. Kevin pastrami brisket ribeye shank tongue short ribs. Doner picanha ham cow tri-tip porchetta.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-5.jpg">
    <p>Short loin jowl brisket picanha ham hock kielbasa cupim doner bresaola pancetta pastrami spare ribs fatback. Flank salami porchetta, hamburger rump cow pig turkey frankfurter. Tail picanha strip steak beef. Tri-tip kielbasa spare ribs turkey.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-7.jpg">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet landjaeger tongue burgdoggen t-bone ham filet mignon pastrami picanha shank strip steak ball tip tail capicola tenderloin ham hock. Brisket tenderloin strip steak, prosciutto bresaola jowl alcatra ham hock kielbasa ribeye pork
      belly pork loin porchetta andouille doner. Swine ribeye shank alcatra fatback bresaola drumstick. Short loin burgdoggen leberkas rump short ribs sirloin shankle meatloaf biltong porchetta ball tip frankfurter shoulder.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: I can not recreate the mentioned issue in my Firefox browswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `background-size:100% 100%;`.

It should fix your problem if i am understanding it correctly.

---

```css
html {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8cmFkaWFsR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imc5NyIgZ3JhZGllbnRVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIGN4PSIwJSIgY3k9IjAlIiByPSIyMDAlIj4KPHN0b3Agc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzc5NDQ0NCIgb2Zmc2V0PSIwIi8+PHN0b3Agc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzExNTU5NCIgb2Zmc2V0PSIxIi8+CjwvcmFkaWFsR3JhZGllbnQ+CjxyZWN0IHg9Ii01MCIgeT0iLTUwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNnOTcpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
body {
  color: #aaa;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 92%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  padding-top: .8em;
}
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 94%;
  width: auto;
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
p {
  text-align: justify;
  word-spacing: -2px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 780px;
  padding: .8em;
}
p,
body,
.content {
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-1.jpg">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet landjaeger tongue burgdoggen t-bone ham filet mignon pastrami picanha shank strip steak ball tip tail capicola tenderloin ham hock. Brisket tenderloin strip steak, prosciutto bresaola jowl alcatra ham hock kielbasa ribeye pork
      belly pork loin porchetta andouille doner. Swine ribeye shank alcatra fatback bresaola drumstick. Short loin burgdoggen leberkas rump short ribs sirloin shankle meatloaf biltong porchetta ball tip frankfurter shoulder.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-2.jpg">
    <p>Frankfurter fatback sausage, turducken chicken short ribs shoulder corned beef ball tip alcatra. Spare ribs brisket sirloin kielbasa short loin, beef ribs jowl porchetta pig prosciutto doner tenderloin. Shankle burgdoggen biltong jowl chuck, landjaeger
      turkey picanha hamburger short loin. Fatback rump tail doner. Brisket cupim meatloaf picanha pastrami. Short ribs doner brisket ground round porchetta shank.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-4.jpg">
    <p>Chuck turkey jowl porchetta. Doner shank swine cupim pastrami pancetta turducken fatback pork tail boudin ham hock ball tip bresaola. Burgdoggen ground round pork flank beef ribs, tri-tip ham tongue spare ribs short loin pork belly boudin meatball
      andouille. Salami ball tip tri-tip doner. Kevin pastrami brisket ribeye shank tongue short ribs. Doner picanha ham cow tri-tip porchetta.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-5.jpg">
    <p>Short loin jowl brisket picanha ham hock kielbasa cupim doner bresaola pancetta pastrami spare ribs fatback. Flank salami porchetta, hamburger rump cow pig turkey frankfurter. Tail picanha strip steak beef. Tri-tip kielbasa spare ribs turkey.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-800-400-7.jpg">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet landjaeger tongue burgdoggen t-bone ham filet mignon pastrami picanha shank strip steak ball tip tail capicola tenderloin ham hock. Brisket tenderloin strip steak, prosciutto bresaola jowl alcatra ham hock kielbasa ribeye pork
      belly pork loin porchetta andouille doner. Swine ribeye shank alcatra fatback bresaola drumstick. Short loin burgdoggen leberkas rump short ribs sirloin shankle meatloaf biltong porchetta ball tip frankfurter shoulder.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in FF(50) by adding these additional background properties to your `<html>` tag:

```css
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Yes! I should add this to the question. background-attachment works great, but it's too expensive - performance wise.

Comment: I was unaware of the performance impact of `background-attachment: fixed;` thanks, glad your issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks! Well, since you brought it up, I looked around. Apparently there's a way to fix the performance issue with background-attachment using psudo elements which is great because I have another project that would look nice with a fixed background and I'd be happy to +1 this answer if implement the fix - https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property